# Customizing MySQL Output

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I'm running the following query and getting an output mentioned below the SQL Query and is explained as follows:

Timestamp: Name of the column which is holding all date and time related values.
MyDatabase: Name of the database
Events:    Name of another column with the name "Events" holding various values like, FIRST, SECOND,THIRD etc. I have mentioned FIRST here for 
convinience and clarity.

```
SELECT count(Timestamp) as COUNT,Timestamp 
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "FIRST" GROUP BY Timestamp ;
```

For example, the output I'm getting is as follows:

```
     COUNT       TIMESTAMP
___________________________
1      1          2013-06-06 11:51:37.0

2      2          2013-06-06 11:51:39.0

3      2          2013-06-06 11:51:37.0
```

and so on....

After long list of occurance of date "2013-06-06", the date changes to "2013-06-07"

The output above is time specific but I want it to be date specific and write down my SQL query in such a way that my desired output should
be as follows:

```
     COUNT       TIMESTAMP
___________________________
1      6          2013-06-06  ( Sum of all the "COUNT" values corresponding to the   date 2013-06-06)

2      8          2013-06-10  ( Sum of all the "COUNT" values corresponding to the date 2013-06-10 )
```

Could you please tell me what could be the modification required so that above output is achieved?

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE(Timestamp)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp to a date, in both the `select` and `group by` clauses.  In MySQL, the easiest way to do this is with the `date()` function:

```
SELECT count(Timestamp) as COUNT, date(Timestamp)
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = 'FIRST'
GROUP BY date(Timestamp)
```

If you very specifically want that format of date, you can also use `date_format()`:

```
SELECT count(Timestamp) as COUNT, date_format(Timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = 'FIRST'
GROUP BY date_format(Timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
```